# What HTML container to use for ASP form instead of HTML table

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I need to know what HTML container to use for ASP form in a way that it can be styled using CSS without using HTML insead of HTML table.

Fore example this form on aspx page:

```
<form id="WPF" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblCCode" Text="Country Code" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCCode" runat="server" Width="85"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lblCName" Text="Country Name" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCName" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lblCPop" Text="Country Population" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPop" runat="server" Width="130"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of DIV's instead of TABLE is well known, lots of stuff to find.

eg http://www.html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/

If it will be simpler I don't know but you got more options.
But if your only goal is to only use CSS for the style of a TABLE, everything about a TABLE can be staled using CSS. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you employ Bootstrap, if you are able.  This is a solution created by the Twitter team and endorsed by Microsoft themselves in their latest templates.  Futhermore, it is mobile/tablet friendly due to its responsive architecture.

Here is a link to some sample code on how to put some form elements on your page:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Craig

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for something simple, like HTML table but a replacement for table.

Comment: Hmm, no such thing.  In the old days we used tables because it was easy, but it was also the wrong way to do it.  Currently, we use DIV tags and CSS to control the layout (and HTML5 attributes for better semantics.)  You can either do all that layout code yourself, or you can hook up one of the many solutions out there which are already done for you.  (Bootstrap, 960.gs, etc.)  From my own experience, using Bootstrap is simpler than defining my own solution.

Comment: @AshrafAbusada Well, what is it then about `table` that isn't "simple"? Just asking because if you're not considering already built frameworks (that make things _trivial_) then....